# Prolog: redundant program points in failure-slice?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice, non-termination, logical-purity

We are implementing diagnostic tools for explaining unexpected universal non-termination in pure, monotonic Prolog programs—based on the concept of the [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice).

As introduced in 
the paper "[Localizing and explaining reasons for nonterminating logic programs with failure slices](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/1999-ppdp-corr.pdf)", goals `false/0` are added at a number of program points in an effort to reduce the program fragment sizes of explanation candidates (while still preserving non-termination).

So far, so good... So here comes my question<sup>1</sup>:

> Why are there N+1 program points in a clause having N goals?

Or, more precisely:

> How come that N points do not suffice? Do we **ever** need the (N+1)-th program point?
>
> Couldn't we move that `false` to each use of the predicate of concern instead?
>
> Also, we know that the program fragment is only used for queries like `?- G, false.`

<sub>**Footnote 1:** We assume each fact `foo(bar,baz).` is regarded as a rule `foo(bar,baz) :- true.`.</sub>

Comment: Sorry for the noise, but my doubt could be related to your... I don't get the notation of the first paper' example (Example 1): P0,...P5 are introduced, so the depicted slice {0,2,4} should be - naively - {5,1,3}. Such mismatch make difficult to me to follow the remainder of the document. Should every 'program point' index be offset by 1 (but then, what happens to P0) ? Could this explain your perplexity ?

Comment: @CapelliC. No, I get that (I think).  Consider the pseudo-code on page 9: `slicep(...,FVect) ←
arg(n1,FVect,1),
sliceq(...,FVect),
arg(n2,FVect,1),
...,
arg(ni,FVect,1),
slicer(...,FVect),
arg(ni+1,FVect,1).`  So IMO that "0-based vs 1-based issue" is only due to the use of `arg/3` to ensure we do not proceed past an inserted `false` goal. So I'd say that the reason for that 0/1-based indices is the use of `arg/3`, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I'm unable to judge... as I said, the initial misunderstanding makes my reading very brittle (hope this make sense, in English)

Comment: @CapelliC: With `{5,1,3}` you are highlighting the points that should be false, but actually, the points that should be true are mentioned.

Comment: @repeat: Extra challenge: How do you handle higher-order predicates. I did not do this, but I really would like to have it.

Comment: @false. I would like to have it, too! As of right now, I don't... At first sight, I'd say that using an extra argument (for transporting the Boolean vector) is troublesome. Using an extra module and some global variable(s), though ugly, *could* work IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are there N+1 program points in a clause having N goals? How come that N points do not suffice?

In many examples, not all points are actually useful. The point after the head in a predicate with a single clause is such an example. But the program points are here to be used in any program.

Let's try out some examples.

#### N = 0

A fact is a clause with zero goals.  Now even a fact may or may not contribute to non-termination.  As in:

```
?- p.

p :-
  q(1).
  p.

q(1).
q(2).
```

We do need a program point for each fact of `q/1`, even if it has no goal at all, since the minimal failure slice is:

```
?- p, false.

p :-
   q(1),
   p, false.

q(1).
q(2) :- false.
```

#### N = 1

```
p :-
   q,
   p.
p :-
   p.

q :-
   s.

s.
s :-
   s.
```

So here the question is: Do we need two program points in `q/0`? Well yes, there are different independent failure slices. Sometimes with `false` in the beginning, and sometimes at the end.

What **is** a bit confusing is that the first program point (that is the one in the query) is always `true`, and the last is always `false`. So one could remove them, but I think it is clearer to leave them, as a `false` at the end is what you have to enter into Prolog anyway. See the example in the Appendix.  There, `P0 = 1, P8 = 0` is hard coded.

Comment: Good to know! Actually, I was thinking along the same lines regarding the `false` at end of the query...

Comment: @repeat: Note that `0` does not immediately translate into an index with `arg/3`...